# Obj-C: I have `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` but target is not responding to selector

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, selector, uigesturerecognizer, uicontrol

I created a class `SYFactory` which contains a variety of class methods used to assemble objects (mostly `UIView`s and `UIControl`s).  These class methods are called by a `UIViewController` object (or more precisely, by an instance of a `UIViewController` subclass called `SYViewController`).

I am trying to add a selector to a `UIControl` object created by `SYFactory`, with the target set as the instance of `SYViewController`.

Thus in `SYFactory`:

```
+ (UIControl*)replyPaneWithWidthFromParent:(UIView*) parent selectorTarget:(id) target
{
//...
    [replyPane addTarget:target
                  action:@selector(showTheVideoPane:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return replyPane;
}
```

And in the `UIViewController` subclass (called `SYViewController`):

```
@interface SYViewController ()

@property (readonly, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pane;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIControl *videoPane;

//...
@end

@implementation SYViewController

@synthesize videoPane;
//...


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...
    self.replyPane = [SYFactory replyPaneWithWidthFromParent:self.pane selectorTarget:self];
}

- (void)showTheVideoPane:(id) sender
{
NSLog(@"Selector selected!");
}
//...
@end
```

When I run the code and I try tapping on the `UIControl` I created, I get an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error.  I do not know why, since I pass the `SYViewController` object as an argument in `+replyPaneWithWidthFromParent:parent selectorTarget:target`.

For some odd reason, the `UIControl` object believes that the message ought not be sent to the `SYViewController` object and tries sending it to an object of a different class instead.  Weird, right?

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

So, right after posting the question I figured out what the problem was (yet another proof that writing things down helps to think them through!):

The `SYViewController` object was created in a local variable inside of a `for` loop.  There being no further references to the object, once the `for` loop terminated the `SYViewController` object was destroyed by ARC.

Faced with a nonexisting target, the `UIControl` object tried to find an object in the responder chain that it thought most likely would answer the message.  That object was of class `SYFixedMarginView`, thus the error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[SYFixedMarginView showTheVideoPane:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f877d60'
```

So the fix is simple.  I assigned the view controller to a `__strong` property in addition to the local variable in the `for` loop.

Hope others don't fall into the same trap.

Comment: The error should say what class the selector was sent to; what does it say? Please paste the whole error.

Comment: It says `SYFixedMarginView` which is a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: actually I just figured out what it is, answer coming momentarily

Comment: apparently I cannot answer my own question not having had enough posts on Stackoverflow, so I've supplied the answer in the question instead